# Hibernate + rest, retrieving only specific columns from one to many depending on context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, one-to-many

My problem: I have two entities User-Comment, One user can have many Comments therefore it is one to many, where comments hold the Foreign Key. The thing is when i retrieve some Comment everything what should be is retrieved, But it also retrieves whole User row, and i want to have only few columns from user row mapping IN THIS SCENARIO, but  i don't want to completely JsonIgnore that fields. Because there are scenarios for example with User-Post (Also one to many) that i need to retrieve them

If you did not understood, then maybe code will make my problem clear:

Code Example:
I have Two hibernate Entities:
User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String username;

@JsonIgnore
private String password;

private String about;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="userRef")
private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

And some Comment entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String text;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="author_id")
private User userRef;
}
```

And my Query inside CommentDao ( it gets comments for given post thats why this is matching it with post_id, i skipped it cuz i don't think it has anything to do with my problem):

```
 session.createQuery("from Comment c where c.postRef.id = :post_id")
                  .setParameter("post_id", postId).getResultList();
```

This produces JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Some comment text",
    "userRef": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "some_username",
      "about": "(**I DON'T WANT THIS HERE**) Something about user"
    }
  }
]
```

My desired JSON output is that everything is the same just without about:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Some comment text",
    "userRef": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "some_username"
    }
  }
]
```

Things i've tried:

- Lazy fetching
- using new() inside HQL , it makes "about"  null
- i know it is possible to do that returning in one response, but i want it to be "nested", so the userRef is just a part of Comment object as it should be

But again, on the other hand, in different scenarios in the same app, i want "about" to be retrievable from other one to many.

I will really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

If you need that field in other context so you have just to create a Wrapper to The User class using Jackson, something like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserMapper {

@JsonProperty
private Integer id;
@JsonProperty
private String username; 
}
```

And map later the user with this class and use it to generate your Json.